# Ayuda para formular un nuevo código PHP

Tags: php

Vengo a este a tratar de pedir retroalimentación de un código que ya tengo, pero me gustaría cambiar la forma en como está ordenado, por otra.

Me gustaría que me sugirieran una manera de lograr esto. Tengo esta función acá abajo que es muy sencilla y fácil, quiero ver de que distintas formas puedo ordenar el siguiente código, ya sea en clases o funciones, esto de una manera limpia y ordenada

```
function Data_Host_Function($url)
{
    $data = array ();
    $data["title"]     = 'Hola Mundo';
    $data['thumbnail'] = "imagen.jpg";
    $data["source"]    = 'YouTube';
    $links             = 'url API';
    $i                 = 0;
    foreach ($links['data'] as $indice => $data_video) {
        $data["data"][$i]['url']     = $data_video['url'];
        $data["data"][$i]["quality"] = $data_video['quality'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $data;
}
#Ejemplo
@$Data_plugin = Data_Host_Function($url);
echo $Data_plugin['title'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez te propondría utilizar una notación un poco más actualizada para los arrays, de forma que obtengas uno con la misma estructura de una forma más sencilla:

```
<?php

function Data_Host_Function($url){
    return [
        'title'=>'Hola Mundo',
        'thumbnail'=>'imagen.jpg',
        'source'=>'YouTube',
        'data'=>$url,
    ];
}

#Ejemplo
@$Data_plugin = Data_Host_Function([
    [
        'url'=>'https://www.web1.com',
        'quality'=>'low',
    ],
    [
        'url'=>'https://www.web2.com',
        'quality'=>'high',
    ],  
]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Data_plugin);
echo '</pre>';
```

Obteniendo:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Hola Mundo
    [thumbnail] => imagen.jpg
    [source] => YouTube
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [url] => https://www.web1.com
                    [quality] => low
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [url] => https://www.web2.com
                    [quality] => high
                )

        )

)
```

Espero que fuera lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios